# referring to innertext hangs chrome

Tags: jquery, arrays, find, each

Code below.  As is, when the Chrome debugger gets to "result.push(...", it never comes back until it crashes.  But if I comment out the "result.push(..." and uncomment the "alert(...", it runs fine, i.e., it shows me each of the lines in my "divedit" div, and it never crashes.  I'm stumped.

TIA

```
function getDivEditLines(divedit) {
    var result = new Array();
    $(divedit).find("div:not(:has('div'))").each(function(){
        result.push($(this)[0].innerText);
        //alert($(this)[0].innerText);
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery why not use `text()`:

```
var getDivEditLines = function ($divedit) {
    var result = [];
    $divedit.find('div')
        .filter(function () {
            return !$(this).find('div').length;
        })
        .each(function () {
            result.push($(this).text());
        });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Tried changing my code to $(this).text(), same thing, it still hangs until CRASH! with msg "Something went wrong while displaying this webpage."  I then tried your code (fixing $divedit.find => $(divedit).find), same thing hang + crash.  Thanks for trying, tho.

Comment: code that finally worked:          var leafs = $(divedit).find("div:not(:has('div'))");
        $.each(leafs, function(key,value){
            result.push(value.innerText);
        });